# Use Taylor's theorem to evaluate the limit

Tags: calculus, limits

The limit that I need to evaluate is $\lim_\limits{x-->x_0} \dfrac{\sin x-\sin x_0}{x-x_0}$.

Comment: $x\to0$ or $ x\to x_0$?

Comment: @oracle I'm sorry to crash your edit suggestion.

Comment: This is a derivative in disguise....

Comment: Is $x$ approaching $0$ or $x_0$?  If it is the latter, the limit is $\frac{\sin(x_0)}{x_0}$.  If it is the former, the limit is $\cos(x_0)$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

If limit is at $x_0$ note that when $f(x)$ si differentiable

$$\lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}=f'(x_0)$$

If limit is at $0$ simply note that $\sin x\to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

The  Taylor serie for $\sin x$ is 
$$\sin x =x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+\frac{x^9}{9!}-...$$
So:
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x -x_0}{x-x_0}= \frac{x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+\frac{x^9}{9!}-...-(x_0-\frac{x_0^3}{3!}+\frac{x_0^5}{5!}-\frac{x_0^7}{7!}+\frac{x_0^9}{9!}-...)}{x-x_0} $$ $$=\frac{x_0-\frac{x_0^3}{3!}+\frac{x_0^5}{5!}-\frac{x_0^7}{7!}+\frac{x_0^9}{9!}-...}{x_0}$$ $$=1-\frac{x_0^2}{3!}+\frac{x_0^4}{5!}-\frac{x_0^6}{7!}+\frac{x_0^8}{9!}-...$$